# Code reuse without libraries

Tags: .net, visual-studio, code-reuse

A while ago I started collecting various repeatedly used classes in libraries. Now the powers that be have decided they didn't want to have those libraries in all these projects.

What would be a "good" alternative instead of going back to copying all this stuff from project to project?

The probably best thing I've come up with so far was using source control to link/share/include the classes in our various projects. Anything better?

Comment: Yea.. What about grouping stuff into smaller DLL's eg DB,Picture,Uplaod,Downlaod,Login... etc instead of one large one? You know like jQuery, then all the plugins on top. What is the reason to not include them? Too big? Too convienient?

Comment: Right now they are a bunch of smaller libraries. As for changing jobs: I like it here. Sometimes they get funny ideas but they rarely last. There are lots of great things here too.

Answer (score 1):

What is their objection?

If they do not want to link with a bunch of smaller libs, you can use  Smart Assembly and create one master assembly, and link your projects to that.

If they want to ship a single binary, you can use Smart Assembly to mash your executable together with it's referenced assemblies, and create a single binary.

Comment: Or just use ILMerge (the official tool from microsoft)

Comment: Smart Assembly is so much kugler.

Comment: Seeing as his company is making a stink about a bunch of 3rd party libraries, a third-party tool might be a problem too.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. I think it may have something to do with a few slip ups in keeping them all current. A second objection I think is that they don't want to have dlls that are not named after our products. There are a number of strange requirements in that regard. For example some of our customers a too stupid to understand the difference between a version x.1 and x.10. While I don't think I could get away with bunching dlls together I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I have a library named common I use just for that purpouse. I put all of my common classes in there.

Answer (score -1):

Some times its better to include the class files instead of making libraries for example you can build your Utility Classes once and you may add those in you projects whenever you need those. This practice gives your power to improve, customize code if ever required. it also enables other developers to view the code, which is really important when one is performing white box testing.